# Split String without delimiter and always different

Tags: c#, split

I'm new in c# and I'm trying to split a string that has no delimiter.
This is the string: "A1020319960855034"
And I want to split it like this:

"A"
"1"
"02"
"03"
"1996"
"08"
"55"
"034"

Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: No, not possible unless you have logic/pattern

Comment: Will the entire string always be the same length?  Will each part of the string always be the same number of characters?  If so you could use String.Substring().

Comment: Yes, the firts sign will always be a letter and the rest will always be a number - thanks

Comment: Only first sign being letter will not help. Do you have a standard pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the entire string has always the same length and each part of the string has always the same number of characters, you can do it like this:

```
string str = "A1020319960855034";
string[] arr = new string[8];
arr[0] = str.Substring(0, 1);
arr[1] = str.Substring(1, 1);
arr[2] = str.Substring(2, 2);
arr[3] = str.Substring(4, 2);
arr[4] = str.Substring(6, 4);
arr[5] = str.Substring(10, 2);
arr[6] = str.Substring(12, 2);
arr[7] = str.Substring(14, 3);
```

Comment: have you noticed word in question subject **always different**

Comment: @Imad Yes, I have. But i think that only the numbers are changing, not the length of the string or the number of characters.